# Apply style to select box with forloop and php

Tags: php, css, select, for-loop

I have a code like this.
If the `$j` or `$get_book_rating` value is '1' then I need to change the select box colour to red or highlight and show the value(if the value is 1). Else let it show the
normal select box with no styles applied. How can I achieve that?

```
    <?php $get_book_rating = $row['book_rating']; ?>
    <select name="<?php echo $bookName ?>" id="<?php echo $bookId ?>">
    <?php for($j=0;$j<2;$j++){ ?>
    <option <?php if($j == $get_book_rating) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $j; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

In other words, I need to check the value of $j and also $get_book_rating and if the value is '1' i need to highlight or show some styles to the select box.
Is that possible.

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: Sorry just seen you're trying to add it to an option - don't think you can style options

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code may be help you- Not tested but you can use logic as i have write:

You can **change condition** as per your requirement

```
<?php $get_book_rating = $row['book_rating']; ?>

<?php 

    $className='';
    $str='';  
    for($j=0;$j<2;$j++){ 
        if($j=='1' || $get_book_rating=='1')  // you need to change condition here as per your requirement
            {
            $className='highlight';
            $str.="<option selected='selected'>". $j ."</option>";
        }
        else        
            $str.="<option>". $j ."</option>";
    }       
    $select="<select name='".$bookName."' id='".$bookId."' class='".$className."'>";
    echo $select . $str ."</select>";

?>


//Define css for class highlight in css like color,width etc
```

Comment: No, this dn't work vijay. The default value is set to '1' in all cases. :( My bad luck ;(

Comment: because value of $j is set to 1 in every loop

Comment: You may need to change condition because in loop condition become true every time

Comment: can you define ...what condition you want?

Comment: Butani Vijay - I need to change the colour of the select box if the value is '1'. How can I achieve that.? Help me out

Comment: But you are using loop in which $j value is set 1 every time, so color is apply every time,can you define condition in comment